# How to attach recorded audio into email? in SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift

I've an app that record voices type of "wav" and send emails ,too.  I want to add that recorded file into the email as attachment?? here is sendEmail code

```
func sendemail(email: String){
    if( MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() ) {
        println("Can send email.")

        let mailComposer = MFMailComposeViewController()
        mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self

        //Set the subject and message of the email
        mailComposer.setSubject("Voice Note")
        mailComposer.setMessageBody("my sound", isHTML: false)
        mailComposer.setToRecipients([email])
// the app doesn't go trough this IF STATEMENT 
        if let filePath1 =      NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("fahad", ofType: "wav") {
            println("File path loaded.")

            if let fileData = NSData(contentsOfFile: filePath1) {
                println("File data loaded.")
                mailComposer.addAttachmentData(fileData, mimeType: "audio/wav", fileName: "fahad")
            }
        }
        self.presentViewController(mailComposer, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have fahad.wav in your bundle? show your folder structure sanpshot.

Comment: Wav files are big. Do you really want to email one?

Comment: You can't modify the app bundle content, record to and read from the app documents directory.

Comment: My app have a ability to record audio after click on recordButtun then will save it in the device under fahad.wav @AshishKakkad

Comment: so what do you think it's better for voice note that I can use it as an email attachment wav/m4a ? @matt

Comment: @Fahad If you are saving it by code then it's not in bundle. it will be in the documents or temp directory.

Comment: I changed the code, it appears in sending email window ,but when I send the email the receiver receives the email with no attachment thanks for your helping I appreciate it `if let docsDir =
  NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as? String {
                    var fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
                    var error: NSError?
                      var filecontent = fileManager.contentsAtPath(docsDir)
                        mailComposer.addAttachmentData(filecontent, mimeType: "audio/x-wav", fileName: fileName)` @AshishKakkad

Comment: @Fahad If attachment is displayed it should be sent.

Comment: the problem was here `var filecontent = fileManager.contentsAtPath(docsDir + "/" + fileName)` I didn't put the right path now it works perfectly I really appreciate your helping man thanks a lot god bless you @AshishKakkad

Comment: @Fahad I have added as an answer. hope it will correct and helpful to others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the answer from the comments, adding answer for other #Programmers :

```
func sendemail(email: String){
    if( MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() ) {
        println("Can send email.")

        let mailComposer = MFMailComposeViewController()
        mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self

        //Set the subject and message of the email
        mailComposer.setSubject("Voice Note")
        mailComposer.setMessageBody("my sound", isHTML: false)
        mailComposer.setToRecipients([email])

        if let docsDir = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as? String {
            var fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
            var filecontent = fileManager.contentsAtPath(docsDir + "/" + fileName)
            mailComposer.addAttachmentData(filecontent, mimeType: "audio/x-wav", fileName: fileName)
        }

        self.presentViewController(mailComposer, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```